# PHP: set_exception_handler not working for error thrown in set_error_handler callback

Tags: php, exception

I have the following code to setup my error/exception handlers:

```
// Set the exception handler
set_exception_handler(function($e) {
    echo 'Exception';
});

// Set the error handler
set_error_handler(function($code, $message, $file, $line) {
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $code, $file, $line);
});
```

I have read numerous articles which have said to throw an exception within the set_error_handler callback function. This should mean I only have to handle exceptions. However the set_exception_handler callback function is never called and instead I get the warning:

> Warning: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message...

Please note that I am using PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to run the PHP script below, and it runs fine.

```
// set the exception handler
set_exception_handler(function($e) {
  echo ' Exception';
});

// set the error handler
set_error_handler(function($code, $message, $file, $line) {
  echo " Error [$message]";
  throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $code, $file, $line);
},-1);

// trigger error
trigger_error('My own error.',E_USER_ERROR);
```

It returns:

> Error [My own error.] Exception

Its exactly the same as yours. I cannot find anything wrong with the piece of code you provided, could the problem be outside it?

Comment: Thanks your example worked fine. However if you try doing "require 'DoesNotExist.php';" instead of "trigger_error(...);" it will call the error handler but not the exception handler.

Comment: PHP manual: "require is identical to include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error.", hence the error message because compile errors are issued before the code is executed. Use 'include' to work with the exception handler. There is a way to make it work. Make a php file that is bug-free and 'includes' two other PHP files: 1. Your error handler. 2. The file you want to debug. That way your error handling routines have been executed before the file to debug is being compiled.